# use python-twitter to retrieve screen_name for valid email

Tags: python, python-twitter

I am trying to leverage the python-twitter wrapper to convert email addresses to twitter username. So far I am trying to the code below but getting an error that states "Sorry, that page does not exist code 34". I am using the latest version of python-twitter and valid keys/secret to access (other python-twitter scripts are working OK).

Here is what I have:

```
import twitter
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='',
                          consumer_secret='',
                          access_token_key='',
                          access_token_secret='')
users = api.GetUserByEmail('testemailaddress123@gmail.com')
for name in users:
    print name
```

This code is based off the python-twitter documentation at: http://static.unto.net/python-twitter/0.6/doc/twitter.html#User

Answer (score 0):

It seems like python-twitter is still using twitter's v1 API, which is being retired on May 7th, 2013. Today, April 16th 2013, [Twitter is performing a blackout test](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/api-v1-retirement-final-dates) in preparation of the deprecation of v1.

You should use Twitter's v1.1 API instead. I believe the following will work for the python-twitter client (haven't tested it).

```
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='',
                      consumer_secret='',
                      access_token_key='',
                      access_token_secret='',
                      base_url='https://api.twitter.com/1.1')
```

**EDIT:** It seems like there is a v1.1 branch of the python-twitter client, which can be found [here](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter/tree/api_v1.1).

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up but looks like this still isnt working... I think the issue is context based with the Python code based on the error...

Comment: Looks like this feature might have been canned: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/612